# how to extract the availability(in stock) in this tag of amazon website in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the info of this product, but the availability in this `<div>` tag is not getting extracted. Instead, only `nbsp` is getting extracted, but the code is working for other tags. Here is the code for extraction. (using `beautifulsoup`)

```
try:
  s4 = soup.find(id='availability').find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
  print(s4)
except:
    print('no availability')
```

Here is the URL of the page: https://www.amazon.in/Redmi-4-Gold-16-GB/dp/B01LYX8UPN

... and I am getting only [\n \n] after running the code instead of 'in stock'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check first if the match is not 'none' something like this:

```
import requests as tt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

get_url=tt.get("https://www.amazon.in/Redmi-4-Gold-16-GB/dp/B01LYX8UPN")  #opening the url
soup=BeautifulSoup(get_url.text,"html.parser")  #parsing the content of page to html parser
sub_class=soup.find("div", {"id": "availability"})  #finding that particular div 
if sub_class:   #above result can be none so checking if result is not none
    print("availability : {}".format(sub_class.find("span", {"class": "a-size-medium a-color-success"}).text.strip()))  #if result is not none then finding sub class which is span and getting the text of span
```

output:

```
availability : In stock.
```

Comment: thanks the code is working but can you explain what actually is happening in each line as i am new in python and that will help me understand it better...

Comment: @swapnilkhatri i have added the comments in code , i hope it will help you.